# I'm having trouble loading data from my csv file into sql

Tags: mysql, codio

I've attempted several times to load my data from my file into my database, but when the statements run they load 0 data.

My data has 8k rows that look like this [file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zE7K.png); and my load data statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/codio/workspace/FleetMaintenanceRecords.csv'

INTO TABLE parts_maintenance

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'

IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

But when I run it nothing loads, and when I try without the termination lines I get the following error:

> ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'VehicleID' at row 1

or this:

> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: 'VehicleID,State,Repair,Reason,YEAR,Make,BodyType' for column 'VehicleID' at row 1

The table I'm loading into looks like this:

```
describe parts_maintenance;

\+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |

\+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

| VehicleID | bigint       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

| State     | varchar(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

| Repair    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

| Reason    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

| YEAR      | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

| Make      | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

| BodyType  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

\+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What am I doing wrong?  I've reached out to my professor, tutors, etc. and no one seems to be able to help!

- Removing the terminated statements
- Updating the csv file in excel and notepad++ to ensure the format matches
- Changed column headers and integer types
- Contacted my professor and the online tutors
- Revised column 1 to ensure they are only numeric values

Comment: [How big is this class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77958750/issue-with-sql-data-not-being-loaded-into-table)

Comment: You might have a Byte-Order Mark (BOM) at the beginning of the file. Load the CSV file with NotePadd++, then click  `Encoding`  on the menu bar. Click `Convert to UTF-8` and then save the file. Try loading it into MySQL again.

Answer (score 1):

There are missing “'” at first and second data line besides extra “,” at the end of first to fourth lines.